# system properties passed in tomcat command line in java

Tags: java, tomcat

i have a web based application which uses tomcat. i want to pass a path to the application when i launch tomcat. i tried the following code so far:

```
startup.bat -DdbPath=c:\DatabasePath
```

I tried reading it in my java code by the following code:

```
String url = System.getProperty("dbPath");
```

The URL returned is null when i run the application. what may be the issue?

Even sending the parameters through catalina.bat start -DdbPath=c:\DatabasePath does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat comes with an empty file called setenv.bat. Just put whatever you want in there and it will get set during startup.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to use Ant scripts for tomcat start. That way it would be better to pass jvm arguements

```
        <java jar="${s.tomcat.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" spawn="${run.background}" fork="true">
            <jvmarg line="-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"/>
            <jvmarg line="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"/>
            <jvmarg line="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"/>
            <jvmarg line="-Xms256m"/>
            <jvmarg line="-Xmx1024m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${s.tomcat.home}"/>
            <arg line="start" />
        </java>
```

Comment: It is wild overkill to use Ant in deployment for simple tasks like this. Ant is a development tool.